# Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME Session stuck on login screen

Tags: gnome, login, 17.10, session

I have Ubuntu 17.10 with the KDE Plasma and GNOME Desktop Environments in which I am able to login without problems with KDE but when I try logging in to GNOME, it freezes on the login screen in which I can move the mouse but nothing else and there is no change. Any solutions?